# Auto generated close as dupe comment appears only after a full reload

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

When casting a close vote (non binding) or raising a flag to mark a question as duplicate of other question, the auto generated comment "Does this answer your question? *[duplicate target link]*" is not being displayed. It's visible only after manually reloading the page.

In the past, it used to load the auto comment automatically, hence I'm considering this a bug.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Acknowledging bug... can't tell when a fix will be in sight.