# Display a message for answerers when a question has pending duplicate votes

Tags: feature-request, answers, duplicate-questions

When a question has pending duplicate votes, a message should be displayed above the answer form.

> Warning: this question is a possible duplicate of [...], are you sure you want to submit an answer?

Example: I vote to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188695/how-to-fix-1-59-0-016949153-without-1-59-0-in-bash-script) as a duplicate. The first answer was a few seconds before my vote, but still new answers were added 3 and 7 minutes later. They're good answers, too, but they should probably have been posted to the original question as to avoid content fragmentation.

I believe it'd be useful to see such a message appear while writing an answer. If that person decides that the close vote is incorrect, he/she can still continue to write and submit an answer.

Comment: We already have the auto generated comment. Those who don't look in comments made on the question before answering won't give any attention even to blinking banner.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I have been once been scorned by a high-rep user that I have downvoted for answering and who would have no excuse under the new system ("how was I supposed to know this was an obvious duplicate?").

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "We already have the auto generated comment" - except that it doesn't currently show up until you refresh (there's a bug about that here somewhere).

Comment: @Dukeling that's not really important, others should see it just fine and probably live update will even bring it live without page refresh, the bug was [reported by yours truly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207378/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm fairly sure auto-comments by others don't trigger the "add / show x more comment(s)" button (but they may load if you click the button after the button was generated by a non-auto comment) (but it's not exactly the easiest thing to confirm).