# Can't un-upvote an auto-upvote on an auto-generated comment

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

I made a poor decision on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57340891/3000206) post, and agreed with the existing close vote. That automatically upvoted the close-comment with an orange upvote.

I re-read the question though, and realized that I actually disagree with that duplicate close, so I retracted my vote. I tried retracting the auto-upvote on the answer though, and was unable to. If I click the orange up arrow to undo it, nothing happens. It stays upvoted.

This likely isn't a problem on my end. As a test, I upvoted a plain comment and gave it a blue upvote. I was able to successfully remove my upvote on that comment by clicking the up arrow again.

I'm guessing this is a bug?

---

Why do I think that this is a problem? The upvote doesn't do anything directly, but I don't want it to show artificial support for the close. While the number of up votes on the comment *shouldn't* effect the chances that someone else will close vote, I'm willing to bet it does have some influence.

Comment: The comment in question does not currently exist. You likely need to refresh the page to view the current comments.

Comment: @Ramhound It's been deleted now because the post was closed. At the time, I did try refreshing the page.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The color varies from site to site. As in Meta, if you upvote, you'll see a light-blue colored arrow, orange in Overflow, blue in Math, green in Chemistry,etc. I too tried voting to close for a duplicate and retracted the vote. The same happened with me.

Comment: Currently, the auto-upvote shows up only after the page has been refreshed, and [refreshing the page anyway prevents retraction of comment upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358572). Even the [auto-generated comment does not appear until the page is reloaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207378), so maybe this bug is related to that.

Comment: Also related: [The automatic comment upvote is not retracted when I retract my duplicate close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350869).