# Unable to undo comment-upvote after page reload

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, voting

Why can't I remove my comment-upvote after I've **reloaded** the page?

I completely understand the reason to 'time-lock' removing your vote ([or question-vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked)), but it seems like reloading the page should not stop me from removing my vote.

[This meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/comment-upvote-undo-and-then-re-upvote-why-not?rq=1) indicates the time-lock to be [1 minute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/cancelling-upvote-on-comment/129032#129032), but reloading the page seems to 'cancel' this timeout.

---

Pressing the comment-vote button, doesn't show any actions, the default popup isn't shown after reloading the page.

**Not shown:**

> Are you sure you want to undo your upvote on this comment?
>
> You will not be able to upvote it again.

**Additionally**, a small note that you can't remove the vote could be useful (same idea at the question vote lock);

> Your vote is now locked in unless this **comment** is edited

Comment: "*You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away*" - I guess reloading the page counts as navigating away.  Might be an FR, then.

Comment: But why? 60 seconds is more than enough for my keyboard-hand to randomly pressed `Ctrl` + `C` without even think about it...

Comment: Yeah, it's a feature-request:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Jzd.png

Comment: Comment votes also do not unlock if the comment is edited after the 60-second timeframe. Once the 60 seconds is up, the comment vote is forever.

Comment: This is practically a bug in my opinion, and, it's one of those just-don't-do-it bugs. I don't see why you would need to reload the page within 60 seconds after upvoting a comment, and considering what Ollie and animuson said, going to another link and going back or something of the sort will cause the 60-second timer to lose track. Nobody really thinks it's a big deal...

Comment: I  do NOT understand the reason to 'time-lock' removing your vote. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318568/allow-un-upvote-and-re-upvote-the-comments-as-many-times-as-user-wants?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When comments first rolled out and you could upvote them, there was no option to undo upvotes at all. They were permanent. It was argued that, especially on mobile devices, it was easy to accidentally click on an upvote for a comment you did not intend to cast and it was then impossible to undo it. So we expanded upvoting comments ever so slightly to allow immediately undoing a comment vote, under some conditions:

- You must still be on the page and cannot have refreshed.
- You must undo it within a minute of casting it.
- You can never upvote the comment again once it's been retracted.

We do not have any interest in further expanding the functionality behind comment votes. The ability to undo a vote on a comment was already a compromise on our part meant only to address users who *accidentally* upvoted a comment when they did not mean to do so, as mentioned above.

The locking mechanism is intentionally short and unforgiving because we assume that you would only ever undo an accidental vote on a comment immediately after accidentally casting the vote, because that is the only use-case we recognize for undoing comment votes.

Regarding your specific suggestion: Comments can only be edited for up to five minutes after they are posted, at which point they would never be edited again (barring a moderator edit, which is extremely rare). Thus locking comment votes until they've been edited would mean that few comments could ever be unvoted **and would explicitly disallow undoing accidental upvotes in many cases**.

Comment: 1. “we assume that you would only ever undo an accidental vote on a comment immediately after accidentally casting the vote” assumption is wrong, as people can recognise that they touched mobile/tablet device much longer than 1 minute. 2.”that is the only use-case we recognize for undoing comment votes.” - people can change their mind over the time after getting new information, and you should recognize such use-case

Comment: This happened while testing another bug, and most certainly was unexpected. >.<

Comment: shouldn't it at least display an error similar to trying to revote after reverting a vote?

Comment: @KevinB sounds like a decent new feature request. ;)

Comment: Why on Earth can't people be allowed to undo upvotes whenever they want in the first place?